# Create Navigation menu off XML file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, xml, nokogiri

I got this rather auld XML file and need parse it using Nokogiri and process using Ruby 2.3.1, and generate an array so I can display a nested link's menu.

[Here is the XML](https://pastebin.com/nD0b7H3u)

So the idea is to have a menu like this:

```
Africa
  South Africa
    Cape Town
      Table Mountain National Park
    Free State
      Bloemfontein
  ...
  Sudan
    Eastern Suda
  ...
  Swaziland
```

I am able to parse the XML and navigate getting the nodes like this:

```
xml_doc.xpath('//node_name')
.map {|n| { name: n.text,
            atlas_node_id: n.parent['atlas_node_id'],
            ethyl: n.parent['ethyl_content_object_id'] } }
```

This just generates and array of hashes but in a flat sort of way, I am having difficulty making an array I can iterate over in my view and achieve the desired result. Any pointers will be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can work with a recursive function to deal with that structure. something like

```
require 'nokogiri'
require 'open-uri'

# Fetch and parse XML document
doc = Nokogiri::XML(open('https://pastebin.com/raw/nD0b7H3u'))

# we have a revursive function that prints the xml by levels
def parse_menu(xml, level)
  level+=1
  xml.xpath("node").each do |menu_item|
    puts "#{" " * level}#{menu_item.xpath("node_name").text}"
    parse_menu(menu_item, level)
  end
end

# we call the function
parse_menu(doc.xpath('taxonomies/taxonomy'), -1)
```

this will print something like:

```
Africa
 South Africa
  Cape Town
   Table Mountain National Park
  Free State
   Bloemfontein
  Gauteng
   Johannesburg
   Pretoria
  KwaZulu-Natal
   Durban
   Pietermaritzburg
  Mpumalanga
   Kruger National Park
  The Drakensberg
   Royal Natal National Park
  The Garden Route
   Oudtshoorn
   Tsitsikamma Coastal National Park
 Sudan
  Eastern Sudan
   Port Sudan
  Khartoum
 Swaziland
```

and of course you just need to modify a little the function, maybe in a helper, to print them in ul and li tags for your menu, because it depends of your frontend